# Javascript Tree Traversal Algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, depth-first-search, tree-traversal

I need help traversing a tree structure in  a depth first fashion. I can't come up with an algorithm to do it properly.

My input is this:

```
[
    ["A", "B", "C"],
    ["1", "2"],
    ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
]
```

The output should take the form:

```
[
    "A/1/a", "A/1/b", "A/1/c", "A/1/d",
    "A/2/a", "A/2/b", "A/2/c", "A/2/d",
    "B/1/a", "B/1/b", "B/1/c", "B/1/d",
    "B/2/a", "B/2/b", "B/2/c", "B/2/d",
    "C/1/a", "C/1/b", "C/1/c", "C/1/d",
    "C/2/a", "C/2/b", "C/2/c", "C/2/d"
]
```

Comment: This can be done, but it's a bit tricky. Is there any way you can reorganise your data? You're going to have trouble coordinating which of `A B C` corresponds to which `1 2` and which `a b c d`; your expected data looks like it follows quite a strange rule. +1 for giving expected data, though.

Comment: Sure. I can manipulate the input in any way. What form would be preferable?

Comment: The easiest way I can think of is to have a child array instead of a sibling array. This is much easier to traverse as a tree-like structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do the job:

```js
function traverse(arr) {
  var first = arr[0];
  var ret = [];
  if (arr.length == 1) {
    for (var i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
      ret.push(first[i]);
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
      var inn = traverse(arr.slice(1));
      for (var j = 0; j < inn.length; j++) {
        ret.push(first[i] + '/' + inn[j]);
      }
    }
  }
  return ret;
}

var inp = [
  ["A", "B", "C"],
  ["1", "2"],
  ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
];

var out = traverse(inp);

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the cartesian product of a list of lists, it has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4797658/201359) before. Borrowing from the accepted answer for that question, you can do this in Javascript 1.7:

```
function product() {
    return Array.prototype.reduce.call(arguments, function(as, bs) {
        return [a.concat(b) for each (a in as) for each (b in bs)];
    }, [[]]);
};

function convert(lst) {
  var solution = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < lst.length; i++) {
    solution.push(lst[i][0] + "/" + lst[i][1] + "/" + lst[i][2]);
  }
  return solution;
};

convert(product(["A", "B", "C"], ["1", "2"], ["a", "b", "c", "d"]));

> ["A/1/a", "A/1/b", "A/1/c", "A/1/d",
   "A/2/a", "A/2/b", "A/2/c", "A/2/d",
   "B/1/a", "B/1/b", "B/1/c", "B/1/d",
   "B/2/a", "B/2/b", "B/2/c", "B/2/d",
   "C/1/a", "C/1/b", "C/1/c", "C/1/d",
   "C/2/a", "C/2/b", "C/2/c", "C/2/d"]
```

Comment: I think you should include the permalink, because in theory they can change the accepted answer and post 100 answers more (and it would be pretty hard to find it then)

Comment: @ajax333221 agreed, I added the permalink as you suggested.

Comment: This is more elegant and more generalized, but it doesn't solve the specific problem and there is an error in the current version.

Comment: @Adam I just updated my answer, I made the code a little more clear but apart from that, I couldn't find the error you were talking about, what's it?

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token for

Comment: @Adam see the quoted [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4797658/201359), this solution works for _Javascript 1.7_

Comment: meh. I know this was an algorithm question but if it doesn't work in chrome stable it's not much use to me.