# Traverse NodeTree with html tags

Tags: java, html, tree, treenode

I have created a tree node,which holds html tags inside and I want to traverse the tree and do some actions in each case to appear things in JTextPane.But I am having trouble to traverse the tree in order to keep the hierarchy.For example i have "h1" tag and "p" tag as its parent.I want to traverse the tree and appear the "h1" tag and then put it in a paragraph.Any idea how I can do that? I hope i was clear...
[Check Photo Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c995L.png)

I think i need something like this.

Comment: I would consider recursion

Comment: @bindrid post order maybe?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "appear things".  Turning on or off node, or turning off and on things in the node or appending things to the node. The answer to that question will determine recursion method, along with intra node dependencies.

Comment: @bindrid I edited it.Check the photo.Does it helps ?

Comment: i found this, it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763641/javascript-tree-traversal-algorithm

Comment: @bindrid I sadly cant understand it cause i am new in programming and i know only java :(

Answer (score 1):

You should use depth-first search. A good tutorial: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/depth-first-traversal-for-a-graph/

Answer (score 0):

You would need each node in the tree to have a reference to its parent to be able to do a traversal up the tree.

EDIT: You can call a recursive function on the 'p' tag, and do a [post-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Post-order) iteration on each child, exclude the root and add each element encountered to the parent tag. Assuming that I'm understanding what you are saying correctly, that is.

Comment: I have done that.I want to traverse the tree like the photo i posted.